# Questions about education and teaching

Tags: discussion, questions

I noticed that this question, [Is there a collection of teaching materials?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/200/is-there-a-collection-of-teaching-materials), has received some controversy, which I was expecting.

It could be said that this style of question falls under than SO Policy of not asking for recommendations and suggestions, rendering it unconstructive.

However, I expect we'll be receiving more questions of this type, since education is the primary intended use of the Raspberry Pi.

Should we be following the SO mantra on these questions or should they be expected and encouraged in the spirit of the foundation?

Answer (score 3):

We should encourage this type of post, but in this particular case, I don't think it is specific enough. (Having said that, I haven't VTCd, because there isn't a better question being asked.)

We should encourage things like "Does anyone know of a lesson plan to teach networking to secondary school children?" or "Has anyone taught any Maths using the RPi?

Comment: Fair enough. I like this compromise.

Comment: I have VTCed.  I don't think we should leave a question open just because there isn't a better one on the same subject yet.  We should consider what will be the average question quality at the point the site goes public.  Too many vague/subjective questions may deter experts from joining.